# There is no file with URL 'Pages/home.aspx' in this Web

Tags: site-template

I am trying to create a subsite based on a custom template. However, I am getting the error below. Anyone any idea what is causing this?

```
[COMException (0x8107058a): <nativehr>0x8107058a</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack><nativehr>0x80070003</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>There is no file with URL 'http://interact.local/sites/commsit/Comm/Pages/home.aspx' in this Web.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.ApplyWebTemplate(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32 fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32 fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, Int32 fIgnoreMissingFeatures, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32& plWebTemplateId) +0
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ApplyWebTemplate(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32 fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32 fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, Int32 fIgnoreMissingFeatures, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32& plWebTemplateId) +290

[SPException: <nativehr>0x80070003</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>There is no file with URL 'http://interact.local/sites/commsit/Comm/Pages/home.aspx' in this Web.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx) +146
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ApplyWebTemplate(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32 fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32 fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, Int32 fIgnoreMissingFeatures, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32& plWebTemplateId) +889
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ProvisionWebTemplate(SPWebTemplate webTemplate, String webTemplateToUse, SPFeatureWebTemplate featureWebTemplate, Page page, SPFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior featureDependencyErrorBehavior, ICollection`1& featureDependencyErrors) +928
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ApplyWebTemplate(SPWebTemplate webTemplate, Page page, SPFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior featureDependencyErrorBehavior, ICollection`1& featureDependencyErrors) +532
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.TemplatePickerUtil.ApplyWebTemplateAndRedirect(SPWeb Web, String strWebTemplate, Nullable`1 bSharedNav, Boolean bOnTopNav, Boolean bOnQuickLaunch, Page page, Boolean bDeleteOnError, SPFeatureDependencyErrorBehavior featureDependencyErrorBehavior, ICollection`1& featureDependencyErrors) +2068
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.NewSubwebPage.BtnCreateSubweb_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +906
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +146
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3586
```

**EDIT 1**

The root site is based on this custom template. So, there is no problem there. There is a home.aspx page created in the pages library in the root site, but when I try to create a subsite it throws the error above.

Comment: Open SharePoint designer and check there is a file exists in that path.

Comment: there is no subsite created, so there will be no file.

Comment: Looks to me that the custom template is created from a site using publishing infrastructure. The pages library gets created when you activated the site feature. Is the custom template created from a site with the feature activated?

Comment: your custom `onet.xml` contains link to `Page/home.aspx`, but your package(wsp) doesn't contain actual file. either remove link or add file.

Comment: I just edited my post. The root site is based on this custom template. So there has been no errors during creation. But the error appears when I create the subsite based on this custom template.

Comment: does the template have home.aspx? is the template setting the welcome page before the page is provisioned?